# SQL Server Always Encryption - Query Stuck in Executing State

Tags: sql-server

We are on - Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU9) (KB5000642) - 15.0.4102.2 (X64)   Jan 25 2021 20:16:12   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)

Configured Always Encryption successfully on the DB server. As part of testing, we removed the cert from the windows cert store and ran the select query with the "Column Encryption Setting=enabled" setting, the query is throwing an error in the message as expected but the query keeps running until I kill it. This is happening in the DB server and from other servers too. Has anyone seen this issue before? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What are you actually asking here? *"Has anyone seen this issue before?"* is just a "yes" or "no" answer.

Comment: Asking if they ever saw this issue and if yes, what did they do to resolve it.

Comment: what is the exact query you are running?

Comment: just the Select * from table and the default select top 1000 rows queries.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because we had symmetric Key Column level Encryption on the same table. We had multiple Symmetric keys, certs from previous testing. Once we removed all of those, the above issue disappeared. I am not sure what the old Symmetric keys had to do with the above issue as it was on another column on the same table but cleaning them up it resolved it.